# Ligando Powerpoint à Access através de VBA?

Tags: banco-de-dados, vba, microsoft-access, powerpoint

Estou criando um tipo de "urna"  no **Power Point** gostaria de 3 (três) soluções básicas para apurar os votos;

1. Ao clicar no botão de confirmar, é enviado automaticamente o voto por **e-mail**, para um determinado endereço de e-mail;
2. Ao clicar no botão de confirmar, é enviado automaticamente o voto para um Banco de Dados no **Access**.
3. Ao clicar no no botão de confirmar, o voto é mandando para uma tabela no final do slide onde poderá ser acessado com uma senha.

---

Também gostaria de que com uma TextBox, o votante colocasse seu nome e depois de votado, fosse enviado para o BD do Access ou por e-mail.

Obrigado :D

Comment: E qual é a sua dúvida? Seja bem vindo ao SOPT. Note, por favor, que este site não é um fórum e muito menos um classificado de busca por profissionais. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask].